# .push() not getting results as expected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

```js
let answerArr = [];
let practicemsg = '';
let correctCounter = 0;
let $practiceButton = $('#practice');

function math() {
  if (correctCounter > 0) {
    correctCounter = 0;
  }
  let operatorArr = ['+', '-', 'x', '/'];
  let expression1 = function(left, right) {
    return +left + +right
  };
  let expression2 = function(left, right) {
    return +left - +right
  };
  let expression3 = function(left, right) {
    return +left * +right
  };
  let expression4 = function(left, right) {
    return +left / +right
  };

  let left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  let right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  let operatorRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  switch (operatorArr[operatorRand]) {
    case '+':
      answerArr.push(expression1(left, right));
      break;
    case '-':
      while (Math.sign(left - right) === -1 || (left - right) === 0) {
        left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
      }
      answerArr.push(expression2(left, right));
      break;
    case 'x':
      answerArr.push(expression3(left, right));
      break;
    case '/':
      while ((left % right) != 0) {
        left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
      }
      answerArr.push(expression4(left, right));
      break;
  }
  let expressionReturned = left + operatorArr[operatorRand] + right + ' = ' + '<br />';
  return expressionReturned;
}
$($practiceButton).on('click', function() {
  $('#page2').toggle();
  if (practicemsg.length > 0) {
    practicemsg = "";
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    practicemsg += math();
    //$("#question").html(practicemsg);
  }
  //console.log(practicemsg);
  $("#question").html(practicemsg);
});
$('.again').on('click', function() {
  if (practicemsg.length > 0) {
    practicemsg = "";
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    practicemsg += math();
    //$("#question").html(practicemsg);
  }
  //console.log(practicemsg);
  $("#question").html(practicemsg);
});
```

```css
#blackboard2 {
  background-color: #425a5a;
  border: 25px solid #523620;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 0.125em;
  display: flex;
}

#question {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 350px;
  align-items: flex-end;
  line-height: 1.7;
}
.answer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="page2">
  <div id="choices">
    <button class="practice" id="practice" name="practice" type="button" value="practice">Practice</button>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="page1">
  <section id="blackboard2">
    <div id="question" class="ques">
    </div>
    <div id="answer" class="answer">
            <input id="1" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer0" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            <input id="2" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer1" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            <input id="3" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer2" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            <input id="4" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer3" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            <input id="5" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer4" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            <input id="6" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer5" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            <input id="7" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer6" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            <input id="8" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer7" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            <input id="9" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer8" size="5" maxlength="5" />
            <input id="10" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer9" size="5" maxlength="5" />
        </div>

  </section>


  <button class="check" id="check" name="check" type="button" value="check">Check</button>

  <button class="again" id="again" name="again" type="button" value="check">Again</button>
</section>
```

Below is how the code looks before trying to move the function out

```js
$(function() {
  let i = 1;
  let $practiceButton = $('#practice');


  let answerArr = [];
  let practicemsg = '';
  let correctCounter = 0;
  $($practiceButton).on('click', function() {
    $('#page2').toggle();
    if (correctCounter > 0) {
      correctCounter = 0;
    }

    let operatorArr = ['+', '-', 'x', '/'];

    let expression1 = function(left, right) {
      return +left + +right
    };
    let expression2 = function(left, right) {
      return +left - +right
    };
    let expression3 = function(left, right) {
      return +left * +right
    };
    let expression4 = function(left, right) {
      return +left / +right
    };
    let mg = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      answerArr.pop();
    }
    while (i < 11) {
      let left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
      let right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
      let operatorRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

      switch (operatorArr[operatorRand]) {
        case '+':
          answerArr.push(expression1(left, right));
          break;
        case '-':
          while (Math.sign(left - right) === -1 || (left - right) === 0) {
            left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
          }
          answerArr.push(expression2(left, right));
          break;
        case 'x':
          answerArr.push(expression3(left, right));
          break;
        case '/':
          while ((left % right) != 0) {
            left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
          }
          answerArr.push(expression4(left, right));
          break;
      }
      practicemsg += left + operatorArr[operatorRand] + right + ' = ' + '<br />';
      i++;
    }

    //console.log(answerArr);
    let $answer = $('input.answerInput');
    //let $a1 = $('input#1');                  
    let $a2 = $('input#2');
    let $a3 = $('input#3');
    let $a4 = $('input#4');
    let $a5 = $('input#5');
    let $a6 = $('input#6');
    let $a7 = $('input#7');
    let $a8 = $('input#8');
    let $a9 = $('input#9');
    let $a10 = $('input#10');
    let aArr = [];
    $('#answer').on('input', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let an1 = $('input#1').val();
      let an2 = $a2.val();
      let an3 = $a3.val();
      let an4 = $a4.val();
      let an5 = $a5.val();
      let an6 = $a6.val();
      let an7 = $a7.val();
      let an8 = $a8.val();
      let an9 = $a9.val();
      let an10 = $a10.val();
      aArr = [an1, an2, an3, an4, an5, an6, an7, an8, an9, an10];
    });

    $('#check').on('click', function compare2() {
      if (correctCounter > 0) {
        correctCounter = 0;
      }
      for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        if (aArr[index] == answerArr[index]) {
          correctCounter++;
        }
      }
      $('#answer').toggle();
      $('#question').html("");
      let letter = '';

      if ((correctCounter / 10) * 100 == 100) {
        letter = 'A+'
      } else if ((correctCounter / 10) * 100 > 89) {
        letter = 'A-';
      } else if ((correctCounter / 10) * 100 > 84) {
        letter = 'B+';
      } else if ((correctCounter / 10) * 100 > 79) {
        letter = 'B-';
      } else if ((correctCounter / 10) * 100 > 74) {
        letter = 'C+';
      } else if ((correctCounter / 10) * 100 > 69) {
        letter = 'C-'
      } else {
        letter = 'Keep Trying';
      }
      $('#question').html('<h1 class="done">' + (correctCounter / 10) * 100 + '%' + '<br />' + '<h2 class="saying">' + letter + '</h2>' + '</h1>');
    });
    $("#question").html(practicemsg);
    if (i == 11) {
      i = 1;
      practicemsg = "";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#blackboard2 {
  background-color: #425a5a;
  border: 25px solid #523620;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 0.125em;
  display: flex;
}

#question {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 350px;
  align-items: flex-end;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.answer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="page2">
  <div id="choices">
    <button class="practice" id="practice" name="practice" type="button" value="practice">Practice</button>
  </div>

</section>
<section id="page1">
  <section id="blackboard2">
    <div id="question" class="ques">
    </div>
    <div id="answer" class="answer">
      <input id="1" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer0" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="2" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer1" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="3" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer2" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="4" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer3" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="5" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer4" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="6" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer5" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="7" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer6" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="8" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer7" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="9" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer8" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="10" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer9" size="5" maxlength="5" />
    </div>
  </section>

  <button class="check" id="check" name="check" type="button" value="check">Check</button>

  <button class="again" id="again" name="again" type="button" value="check">Again</button>
</section>
```

Not sure what I did wrong but I had this math function connected to practiceButton, works fine but now I want to move it out as a stand alone function so when I click "again" it will just run the function giving me ten more math problems instead of having to refresh the page. I have it pushing the answer into an array because I have a "check" button that will check the answer array to an array of inputed answers. My question is why or what am I missing that it's not pushing into the answerArr. I checked logging what's being returned from the expression and it's giving me the answer but it's not pushing into the answerArr array.

Comment: Don't understand the connection of the duplicate code. Can you please put all this is a [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: the practiceButton code was just to show that was my original code but then I thought to add "what if you wanted ten more question" so that's where my problem comes in trying to get a "again" button

Comment: Where did `$practiceButton` come from?

Comment: added it to the snippet

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are expecting versus what you are getting. It's not clear where the issue lies as it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is hit the "again" button and run math again so I can get another set of ten questions in order to compare to my own array and see which ones are right

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
let answerArr = [];
let practicemsg = '';
let correctCounter = 0;
let $practiceButton = $('#practice');
let operatorArr = ["+", "-", "x", "/"];

var math = {
  add: function(left, right) {
    var result = NaN;
    if (!isNaN(left) && !isNaN(right)) {
      result = left + right;
    }
    return result;
  },
  subtract: function(left, right) {
    var result = NaN;
    if (!isNaN(left) && !isNaN(right)) {
      result = left - right;
    }
    return result;
  },
  multiply: function(left, right) {
    var result = NaN;
    if (!isNaN(left) && !isNaN(right)) {
      result = left * right;
    }
    return result;
  },
  divide: function(left, right) {
    var result = NaN;
    if (!isNaN(left) && !isNaN(right)) {
      result = left / right;
    }
    return result;
  }
}

function initPractice() {

  let left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  let right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  let operatorRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  switch (operatorArr[operatorRand]) {
    case '+':
      answerArr.push(math.add(left, right));
      break;
    case '-':
      while (Math.sign(left - right) === -1 || (left - right) === 0) {
        left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
      }
      answerArr.push(math.subtract(left, right));
      break;
    case 'x':
      answerArr.push(math.multiply(left, right));
      break;
    case '/':
      while ((left % right) != 0) {
        left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
      }
      answerArr.push(math.divide(left, right));
      break;
  }
  let expressionReturned = "<div class='equation'><span class='left'>" + left + "</span><span class='operator'>" + operatorArr[operatorRand] + "</span><span class='right'>" + right + '</span> = </div>';
  return expressionReturned;
}

$($practiceButton).on('click', function() {
  $('#page2').toggle();
  if (practicemsg.length > 0) {
    practicemsg = "";
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    practicemsg += initPractice();
  }
  $("#question").html(practicemsg);
  console.log(answerArr);
});

$('.again').on('click', function() {
  if (practicemsg.length > 0) {
    practicemsg = "";
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    practicemsg += initPractice();
  }
  $("#question").html(practicemsg);
});
```

```css
#blackboard2 {
  background-color: #425a5a;
  border: 25px solid #523620;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 0.125em;
  display: flex;
}

#question {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 350px;
  align-items: flex-end;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

#question .equation {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.answer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="page2">
  <div id="choices">
    <button class="practice" id="practice" name="practice" type="button" value="practice">Practice</button>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="page1">
  <section id="blackboard2">
    <div id="question" class="ques">
    </div>
    <div id="answer" class="answer">
      <input id="1" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer0" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="2" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer1" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="3" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer2" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="4" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer3" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="5" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer4" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="6" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer5" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="7" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer6" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="8" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer7" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="9" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer8" size="5" maxlength="5" />
      <input id="10" class="answerInput" type="text" name="answer9" size="5" maxlength="5" />
    </div>

  </section>


  <button class="check" id="check" name="check" type="button" value="check">Check</button>

  <button class="again" id="again" name="again" type="button" value="check">Again</button>
</section>
```

This groups the math equations in a Object for easier reference. It is not a good practice to define function inside another function when possible.

I also wrapped the equation and it's part1s for easier styling.

Comment: Thank you for this!